# Easier custom navigation management for MvvmCross

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

Hi MvvmXross/Xamarin devs,

This is more of a question for expanding MvvmCross rather than fixing a bug in it. I just need some pointers so I can go about this the right way instead of banging my head on the wall for extended periods of time.

I've been developing using Xamarin & MvvmCross for a while now using Activities and mainly fragments. This works completely fine, but the lifecycle management of the Fragments are (in my opinion) pretty bleh.

I recently worked on a pure Android project and got to using [Flow](https://github.com/square/flow) accompanied by [Dagger](https://github.com/square/dagger). Which made lifecycle management and custom navigation pretty easy.

---

**Simple Flow explanation**

The way flow works is pretty similar to fragments in the general sense (not the lifecycle). There's one activity with a 'Main View' and the library replaces that view when navigation is required, and also keeps track of the history of navigation events.

---

I created a bindings library for Flow only (I don't need the dependency injection Dagger provides) and started with a project to test it out. I have setup flow to take over my main container view and everything is fine. I have a custom AndroidViewPresenter which does checks and ends up calling Flow's navigational methods, So my navigation is still done in the .Core project through the viewmodels.

The problem I'm having now is doing BindingInflates with the views so I can leverage the Binding code that MvvmCross has already. Every flow view has to inherit from a layout type (relative, linear, frame). I can do manual view model creating from the locator and supply the viewmodel to the view, but I'm struggling to figure out how to bind the values so that it responds to RaiseProperty changed in the viewmodel.

I feel ashamed to say that the solution doesn't have to be very sophisticated, I would just like to get an idea of how to accomplish this so I can start testing it out on some apps I have in mind.

Any help/pointers would be grately appreciated.

Comment: Hey Dane, let's have a discussion about this on Slack. We are interested in looking into improving this!

Comment: @Martijn00 I' on my way :)

Comment: @Martijn00 I've joined the Xamarin channel username: danemackier, I also joined the MvvmCross channel but can't seem to find you. When you get some time we can start a discussion around how to accomplish this. Talk soon